# How to rectify ConcurrentModificationException in android

Tags: android, android-calendar

In my application, I am using an extended calendar view; in this I am storing some events.

After that, when I open the calendar, it shows `ConcurrentModificationException`.

How do I solve that problem? I am storing events in database and it shows in calendar?

Comment: What is "extended calendar view"? How are you "storing some events" in a view? How are you "opening the calendar"? What is the complete stack trace for your `ConcurrentModificationException,`? What is the source code from your app that is triggering the `ConcurrentModification`Exception`?

Comment: This link shows about "Extended Calendar view".        https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView

Comment: In this calendar they are storing Events in database just see " CalendarProvider " class in this project.                                  So if i will store many number of events in calendar those are stored into database,and when i open the calendar it retrieves data from database to show the events.

Comment: 12-16 15:36:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(31490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 15:36:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(31490): Process: com.example.demo, PID: 31490
12-16 15:36:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(31490): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
12-16 15:36:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(31490):  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
12-16 15:36:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(31490):  at com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.Day.getColors(Day.java:98)
12-16 15:36:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(31490):  at com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.CalendarAdapter.getView(CalendarAdapter.java:141)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a for each loop and changing the object whilst iterating you get that error. Try using a traditional loop with indexes and you should not run into that.

Comment: I am using traditional "for loop" only like this for(int i=0;i<events.size();i++)